# noflo cannot shutdown execution

Tags: noflo

I'm trying to run some simple graph using [noflo-filesystem](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-filesystem) and [noflo-csv](https://github.com/sirwobin/noflo-csv) that reads CSV file, parses it and writes it down to file.
The issue is that the program waits for something that I don't know how to provide:

*graph.fbp*

```
Read(filesystem/ReadFile) OUT -> CSV ParseCSV(csv/ConvertCsvToMatrix)
ParseCSV OUT -> IN Write(filesystem/WriteFile)    
'dump.csv' -> FILENAME Write(filesystem/WriteFile)
'data.csv' -> In Read
```

When I run

```
.\node_modules\.bin\noflo-nodejs --graph graphs\graph.fbp --batch --register=false --debug
```

I get:

```
DATA -> FILENAME Write() CONN
DATA -> FILENAME Write() DATA
DATA -> FILENAME Write() DISC
DATA -> IN Read() CONN
DATA -> IN Read() DATA
DATA -> IN Read() DISC
DATA -> ENCODING Read() CONN
DATA -> ENCODING Read() DATA
DATA -> ENCODING Read() DISC
Read() OUT -> CSV ParseCSV() CONN
Read() OUT -> CSV ParseCSV() < ..\python_code\web_app\TimeSeries.csv
Read() OUT -> CSV ParseCSV() DATA
Read() OUT -> CSV ParseCSV() > ..\python_code\web_app\TimeSeries.csv
Read() OUT -> CSV ParseCSV() DISC
ParseCSV() OUT -> IN Write() CONN
ParseCSV() OUT -> IN Write() DATA
```

And then the program is hanging.

I tried to feed `Write`'s IN port with just a string like:

```
Read(filesystem/ReadFile) OUT -> CSV ParseCSV(csv/ConvertCsvToMatrix)
'some text' -> IN Write(filesystem/WriteFile)    
'dump.csv' -> FILENAME Write(filesystem/WriteFile)
'data.csv' -> In Read
```

And this works fine:

```
DATA -> IN Write() CONN
DATA -> IN Write() DATA
DATA -> IN Write() DISC
DATA -> FILENAME Write() CONN
DATA -> FILENAME Write() DATA
DATA -> FILENAME Write() DISC
DATA -> IN Read() CONN
DATA -> IN Read() DATA
DATA -> IN Read() DISC
DATA -> ENCODING Read() CONN
DATA -> ENCODING Read() DATA
DATA -> ENCODING Read() DISC
```

Would anyone be so kind to advise how can I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `csv/ConvertCsvToMatrix` is not sending `disconnect` on its output port. This causes NoFlo to believe that the network is not done running yet, so the process is not shutdown. Both of the `.send()` calls in [the component](https://github.com/sirwobin/noflo-csv/blob/master/components/ConvertCsvToMatrix.coffee#L45) must be followed by a `.disconnect()` call.

This can be seen from the --debug output in that it ends with:

`ParseCSV() OUT -> IN Write() CONN
ParseCSV() OUT -> IN Write() DATA`

Compare with the successful example which ends with

`DATA -> ENCODING Read() DISC`

Answer (score 1):

With NoFlo 0.8 we have a new method for seeing what processes are keeping the network alive:

`network.getActiveProcesses` returns an array of process IDs for processes that are currently active.

This is useful for finding badly-behaving components.